# d3 - amending arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of date that has been repeated several number of times.

I've managed to take the unique values from it using the below function.

```
var m = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
            .rollup(function(d) {return d.Date;})
            .entries(data);
```

Here's the data output.

```
    [
      {
        "key": "2014-01-01"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-02"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-03"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-04"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-05"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-06"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-07"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-08"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-09"
      },
      {
        "key": "2014-01-10"
      }
```

I wanted to amend that array something like this.

```
    ["2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-05"]
```

Any help will be very much thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting value of `m` ,you can use following code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93u8h/)**:

**JS**:

```
 var arr=[];
 m.forEach(function(d){ 
    arr.push(d.key)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If `m` contains the data output array, you can get the new array(containing just the `key` values) using

`var mOnlyKeys = m.map(function(elem){return elem.key});`